# Rails upload static image url to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I need to copy images from static image url which are stored in database tables
like : https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b8c19609aaa9eb291f2a5974e369e2a4?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

to s3 using ruby on rails

Comment: What you really want to do, can you please explain more in detial ?

Comment: You mean to say you want to upload image from this url to s3?

Comment: i need to copy this particular image to s3

Comment: After image was copied you should paste it to s3. Nothing more

Comment: i have those url in database tables, i need to copy them dyanamically.

Answer (score 5):

Try out following code:

AWS::S3::S3Object.store(path,content,bucket)

Here, path is the path in the bucket where you want to store, content is the contents which you want to store in that file and bucket is the name of the bucket.

Before this you have to establish connection. So your final code might look like this:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
        :access_key_id     => <key>,
        :secret_access_key => <access_key>,
        :use_ssl           => true,
    )

AWS::S3::S3Object.store(path,open('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b8c19609aaa9eb291f2a5974e369e2a4?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'),bucket)
```